# See if all items in a list = certain string

Tags: python

How would I find if I have a list of a given string, 'hello':

```
x = ['hello', 'hello', 'hello']
# evaluates to True

x = ['hello', '1']
# evaluates to False
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This ought to work:

```
# First check to make sure 'x' isn't empty, then use the 'all' built-in
if x and all(y=='hello' for y in x):
```

Nice thing about the `all` built-in is that it stops on the first item it finds that doesn't meet the condition.  This means it is quite efficient with large lists.

Also, if all of the items in the list are strings, then you can use the `lower` method of a string to match things like `'HellO', 'hELLO', etc.

```
if x and all(y.lower()=='hello' for y in x):
```

Answer (score 14):

Use the [`all()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all) to test if a condition holds `True` for all elements:

```
all(el == 'hello' for el in x)
```

The `all()` function takes an iterable (something that produces results one by one) and will only return `True` itself if all those elements are true. The moment it finds anything that is false, it'll return `False` and not look further.

Here the iterable is a generator expression, one that executes an equality test for each element in the input sequence. The fact that `all()` stops iterating early if a false value is encountered makes this test very efficient if the test in the contained generator expression is False for any element early on.

Note that if `x` is *empty*, then `all()` returns `True` *as well* as it won't find any elements that are false in an empty sequence. You could test for the sequence being non-empty *first*:

```
if x and all(el == 'hello' for el in x):
```

to work around that.

Comment: @JonClements: was getting to that. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Yet another way to do what you want (`all` is the most idiomatic way to do that, as all other answers note), useful in case if you need to check more than once:

```
s = set(l)
cond = (len(s) == 1) and (item in s)
```

It helps to avoid `O(n)` traversal every time you want to check the condition.

Answer (score 1):

Using filter and len is easy.

```
x = ['hello', 'hello', 'hello']
s = 'hello'
print len(filter(lambda i:i==s, x))==len(x)
```

Answer (score 1):

Youn can do that using `set`:

```
set(x) == {'hello'}
```